# How to correctly manipulate and validate editText of type number in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm having problems in my tests with the `editPages_book` and `editYear_publication` variables in the `RegisterBook` and `BookAdapter` files, these variables **only accept integers** and I can't properly validate these fields in these codes described, because my codes don't work correctly because of these fields.

- `activity_register_book.xml`

```
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPages_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:hint="Enter the number of pages"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editYear_publication"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:hint="Enter the year of publication"
            android:inputType="number" />
```

- `RegisterBook.java`

```
        editPages_book = findViewById(R.id.editPages_book);
        editYear_publication = findViewById(R.id.editYear_publication);

        int pages_book = Integer.parseInt(editPages_book.getText().toString());
        int year_publication = Integer.parseInt(editYear_publication.getText().toString());

        if (pages_book <= 0 || year_publication <= 0) {
           Toast.makeText(RegisterBook.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

- `BookAdapter.java`

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            final Book f_book = books.get(position);
            holder.editPages_book.setText(Integer.toString(f_livro.getPages_book()));
            holder.editYear_publication.setText(Integer.toString(f_book.getYear_publication()));
           
            holder.button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pages_book = Integer.parseInt(holder.editPages_book.getText().toString());
                    int year_publication = Integer.parseInt(holder.editYear_publication.getText().toString());
                    if (pages_book <= 0 || year_publication <= 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass the correct resource id to your findViewById method?
`editYear_publication = findViewById(R.id.Year_publication)` might be `editYear_publication = findViewById(R.id.editYear_publication)`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it was incomplete. But your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Boranoro Well I think  `EditText.setText(Integer.toString(some integer))` should work fine with inputType of number. Maybe you can put breakpoints to this line and check if the argument was passed in as expected,  not over the maxLength, etc.